# Can't transform my query with Op.Like into Op.Contains without breaking my Sequelize Code

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following query that work's without problems:

```
return await this.model.findAndCountAll({
        where: { 
            [`${field}`]: { [Op.like]: `%${params[field]}%` } ,
            mentor: `1`,
            [Op.or]: [
                {
                    city: { [Op.like]: `%${params[localizationField]}%` } ,
                },
                {
                    state: { [Op.like]: `%${params[localizationField]}%` } ,
                }
            ]  
        },
        include: [
            {
                model: MentorCategory,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Category,
                        where: {
                            name: { [Op.like]: `%${params[categoryField]}%` },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },  
        ], 
        order: [
            [order, sort]
        ],
        offset: paginate.offset,
        limit: paginate.perPage
    })
```

But if i try to change the [Op.like] to [Op.contains] (i need this to do a query when passing more than one value in params[categoryField], like [ 'Em', 'pr' ]) i receive the following error:

> "Error List: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near '@> '%Em,pr%' ) ON `person`.`id` =
> `mentorCategories`.`person_id` WHERE (`person`' at line 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Op.contains` is Postgres-only operator.

ref: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#postgres-only-range-operators

Though, I see in error message that you are using MySQL.
For MySQL, you can use `Op.regexp` instead.

```
where: {
    name: { [Op.regexp]: `${params[categoryField].join('|'}` }
}
```

This will generate query like this.

```
... `name` REGEXP 'Em|pr' ...
```

This will match name where it contains either "Em" or "pr".

Comment: Thank's Emma. You've resolved the problem.

Comment: Could you accept my answer, if this resolved? Thanks